# ¿Cómo sobreescribir una imagen en php?

Tags: php

Tengo este código para subir imágenes de perfil de usuario.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../db_files/db.php");
$newname = "user_".$_SESSION['id']."_profile_image";
$imagename = "image".$_SESSION['id'];
$oldname = basename($_FILES[$imagename]['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($oldname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$finalname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $newname.'.'.$extension);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['id']);
    if ($_FILES[$imagename]['error'] > 0){
        echo "Error";
    } else {
    $path = "../res/user_uploads/".$_FILES[$imagename]['name'];
    if(!file_exists($path)){
        $imgresult = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[$imagename]['tmp_name'], "../res/user_files/profile_image/{$finalname}");
        $strSQL = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `profile_image` = '$finalname' WHERE `usuarios`.`id` = $id;";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    } else {
        echo $_FILES[$imagename]['name'].", this file alredy exists";
    }
}
?>
```

Sube las imágenes correctamente, pero mi problema llega cuando ya hay una imagen con el nombre. Lo primero es que no me imprime la linea de `This file alredy exists` que debería escribir y por otra parte, no sé como hacer que se sobrescriba una imagen si ya existe, ya que es un cambio de imagen de perfil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta ha sido la solución al final, en vez de comprobar si existe o no, directamente saco de la base de datos la imagen actual del usuarios y la elimino para poner en su lugar la otra.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../db_files/db.php");
$newname = "user_".$_SESSION['id']."_profile_image";
$imagename = "image".$_SESSION['id'];
$oldname = basename($_FILES[$imagename]['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($oldname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$finalname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $newname.'.'.$extension);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['id']);
    if ($_FILES[$imagename]['error'] > 0){
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $strRemove = "SELECT profile_image FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id";
        $removequery = mysqli_query($db, $strRemove);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($removequery);
        unlink("../res/user_files/profile_image/".$result['profile_image']);
        $imgresult = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[$imagename]['tmp_name'], "../res/user_files/profile_image/{$finalname}");
        $strSQL = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `profile_image` = '$finalname' WHERE `usuarios`.`id` = $id;";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Considera que [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php), según la documentación, *si el archivo destino ya existe se sobrescribirá*.

Comment: Pero no me lo sobreescribe...

Comment: Una pregunta que me surge ahora, ya que no he trabajado mucho con el tema de subir imágenes o archivos en general `if (!file_exists($path))` el `!` significa que si existe o que no existe?

Comment: `!` es un [*operador lógico*](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php), lo que hace es **negar el valor devuelto por** [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php). Por ejemplo, si `file_exists` devolviera `true`, entonces `!file_exists`, seria `false`

Comment: Entonces por qué está mal en el código inicial? Es decir, tengo un `if` comprueba que no haya un archivo igual al que subo, si no lo hay mueve el archivo, `else` imprime el error... Creo...

Comment: No se va por el else ya que tampoco me imprime el `echo` que hay dentro del else...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48741/discussion-between-marcos-gallardo-and-pavlo-b).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!file_exists($path)){
    unlink($path); // Eliminamos la imagen previa si existe.
}

$imgresult = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[$imagename]['tmp_name'], "../res/user_files/profile_image/{$finalname}");
$strSQL = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `profile_image` = '$finalname' WHERE `usuarios`.`id` = $id;";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido tu respuesta para darme cuenta de una cosa y una forma más facil de hacerlo. Lo edito en el OP